# Orthonormal basis of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $V$ be a space with inner product $B$ and let $f$ be a self-adjoint linear operator.

I need to show that the matrix of $f$ is symmetric with respect to any orthonormal basis of $V$.

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? :)

Comment: so i need to show that if A is the matrix of f with respect to any orthonormal basis, then A transposed is equal to A right?

Answer (score 1):

Let ${v_1,...v_n}$ be a basis of $V$.

Then $f(v_j)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}v_i$ and we know that as f is self adjoint $<f(v),w>=<v,f(w)>$.

So we get that

$a_{jk}=< v_j, \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ik}v_i>=<v_j,f(v_k)>=<f(v_j), v_k)>=<\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}v_i, v_k>=a_{kj}$